# Multiple Companies for one Developer Account?

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program

Hi I'm in the process of developing a number of apps for a few companies. I've noticed on the App Store that when an app is published there is also a link for "more from this developer". Since the apps I am developing are completely unrelated will I have to register a seperate developer account for each App? Or am I able to set different company names/ prevent users from discovering other apps made from the same account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the applications to appear to be from different developers then you'll need separate accounts. If this is what you need then I'd get the companies that you are developing for to get an account and use that to publish it for them. That way they'll be able to have access to their apps and their reports without having access to your other client's data. If you don't mind the links then it is a way to save some money and make the administration easier, though providing stats is slightly more involved.